# I can't find file `luavlna'

Tags: luatex, input

For some reason, the package luavlna doesn't seem to be working. I am using MiKTeX and have the luavlna package installed. When I try the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{luavlna}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

It gives the following error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luavlna/luavlna.sty:4: I can't find file `luavlna'. [\input luavlna]
```

I have both `luavlna.tex` and `luavlna.sty` in the directory of the error message, so it's odd that it can't find it.

Comment: https://miktex.org/Package/Browse/luavlna suggests that MikTeX fails to install `luavlna.tex` in the runtime directory. This should be reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues. If you do have `luavlna.tex` in the runtime folder how did it get there? Did you install it manually? If you did so, did you remember to refresh the FNDB?

Comment: Yes, I installed it manually. I forgot to mention that, my apologies. I will try to refresh FNDB.

Comment: Even if that helps, **I *strongly* urge you to report the missing package file to the MikTeX maintainer**. He is usually very responsive to issues like this and they will be fixed quickly. But to fix issues like this he has to know about them.

Comment: I will try to do that, but I am quite new to TeX and reporting TeX-relatex issues in general, what would be the best way to report a problem like this?

Comment: OK, I'll report the missing file and will link the report here so you can have a look. Note that this report is a bit different from a normal bug report to a package maintainer.

Comment: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MikTeX package for `luavlna` was missing the runtime file `luavlna.tex` (presumably because for LaTeX packages files with the `.tex` extension are often the source of the documentation and MikTeX does not usually install the source of the documentation).

The issue was reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/86 and has been fixed. An update should resolve the issue.

The workaround previously part of this answer has been removed because it has become obsolete. See the revision history in case you are interested.